# Variable inside href inside php as a query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, href

I'm trying to run my sql query with my php in my code, but I'm not able to make it run.

Here's my query:

```
$sql = ee()->db->query("update exp_store_orders set shipping_company = '<a href='$png_code'>ciao</a>' where id = '$order->id'");
```

Don't focus on the first part, it's expressionengine.

The problem is that I'm trying to put a variable inside it but it's not working. With a double quote it will brake my code and with a single quote is not working..

Any suggestion?

Comment: Having HTML in your database is usually a super bad plan.

Comment: I know! I hate to mix content, but I have in this case because the system is working with extension so in that case is virtually impossible to ad html later

Comment: You're deep into the danger zone, so if you've got any other way it's worth exploring that. In any case you **must** use prepared statements with placeholder values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What You Asked

You need either braces (`{...}`) or string concatenation *if* you're going to do it this way. (You absolutely should *not* do it this way, as explained below.)

Examples:

```
$sql = ee()->db->query("update exp_store_orders set shipping_company = \"<a href='$png_code'>ciao</a>\" where id = '{$order->id}'");

// or

$sql = ee()->db->query("update exp_store_orders set shipping_company = \"<a href='$png_code'>ciao</a>\" where id = '" . $order->id . "'");
```

## Why That's the Wrong Approach

***BUT*** this is not the right way to do it. You should be using prepared statements, not concatenating data directly into your query. Doing it the way you're doing it leaves you open to SQL injection. In theory, you have perfect control over `$order->id` and are 100% sure it's safe. In practice, you don't and you aren't.

## Other Problems

Also, if `$order->id` is a number, you shouldn't have it in single quotes. But that doesn't really matter because, again, you should be using a placeholder there, not a concatenated value.

One more thing: note the escaping of the `"`s above, as in `\"`. You can't set a value like `shipping_company = '<a href='$png_code'>ciao</a>'` because the database thinks the string ends after `href=`; it doesn't know what to do with anything outside of `'`s when you build a string this way.

Comment: To clarify, one way to do this with prepared statements using ExpressionEngine is `ee()->db->query("UPDATE exp_store_orders SET shipping_company = ? WHERE id = ?", array('ciao', $order->id));` Or your first value could be HTML if you wanted, so instead of `'ciao'` you could put `'<a href='.$png_code.'>ciao</a>'`

Comment: It's the png code that part that it's not working, the other part is working fine. Espressionengine has it's own sanitation for data

Comment: @matto yes, EE has its own sanitation IF you use it, but you're not using it and are instead just executing a raw query. See https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/database.html for more info on how to use other prepared statements with parameters. Feel free to join the ExpressionEngine Slack channel (https://expressionengine.com/community#slack) for more specific help with this one - they're very helpful there and will guide around best practices.

Comment: @Matto See my edit above. And as WOUNDEDStevenJones points out, you are not making use of any sanitization features. If, somehow, `$order->id` gets set to something like `1' or 1=1 -- ` (as a *mild* example), you will get hacked.

Comment: Minor update - my solution above is actually missing quotes, so the first value you should pass into the parameter array should be `'<a href="'.$png_code.'">ciao</a>'` (the single quotes and `.` are creating a string in PHP, while the double quotes are part of the generated string to define the `href` value, so you end up with something like `<a href="image.png">ciao</a>` instead of `<a href=image.png>ciao</a>`